# What is the difference between Ensemble and Orchestra?

Tags: classical-music, orchestra, ensemble

Both the definitions imply a group of musicians playing a piece together. If i am inferring it wrong, kindly clarify the difference.  [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An orchestra, at least in Western culture, usually has a fairly specific selection of instruments from which the orchestra is comprised ("orchestral instruments"). In contrast, an ensemble can be any collection of instruments, voices, dancers. An orchestra is always an ensemble, but not all ensembles are orchestras.

The specific instruments 'required' in an orchestra changed over time. In the Baroque period, it was common to have a string section (violins, violas, celli, basses), a couple of wind instruments (oboes, horns were common) and perhaps even a harpsichord. This changed through the Classical period, and by the Romantic period there were vast swathes of brass and woodwind instruments and a much larger string section. There was also more variety in percussion instruments.

A "wind orchestra" is an orchestra entirely comprised of wind instruments; a "chamber orchestra" is a smaller version of an orchestra but generally comprising of similar instruments to a full-size orchestra, except where impractical or unbalancing in terms of volume.

Comment: Welcome! Great first answer!

Comment: Well, sort of -- Duke Ellington lead a jazz orchestra in the terminology of his time.

Answer (score 3):

An orchestra will refer to a specific set of instruments, as Beth mentioned. There is usually a qualifying descriptor in front of it. A symphony orchestra refers to the group we normally associate with classical symphonies and tone poems. There are non-classical orchestras, too, like Big Band Orchestras and Gamelan Orchestras. Both refer to specific sets of instruments that play those kinds of music.

Comment: And everyone's favourite, ukulele orchestras...

Comment: 'Big Band Orchestra'  isn't an accepted term.  Just 'Big Band'.

Comment: This is new information to me. I based my answer on the Count Basie Orchestra, and I don't believe he was the only one to call his group an orchestra instead of a Big Band. Please explain why Big Band Orchestra is not an accepted term.

Comment: @LaurencePayne  you are misleading here.  Big Band ensembles often were called Orchestras back in their heyday.  Just not both names together.

Answer (score 3):

To the best of my knowledge, no vocal ensemble has ever been called an orchestra (pleading for experts to correct me here :-)  ).  Similarly, it's common for a combined performance to be "orchestra and chorus" rather than just "orchestra,"  so while "vocal ensemble" is a common term, as well as "instrumental ensemble," I  think 'orchestra' is pretty much limited to instrumental groups.

Comment: I pretty much agree with your terminology and definition and as an opinion would not classify "Electric Light Orchestra" an orchestra, but an ensemble instead.

Comment: @skinnypeacock   and thus the difference between  a category and a name :-) .

Answer (score 2):

We (sort of) know what a Symphony Orchestra is.  Apart from that, as previous answers have demonstrated, the term is pretty much up for grabs.   We might be fairly confident in saying that (unless used ironically) 'Orchestra' implies a sizeable group of players. But not necessarily THAT big.

'Ensemble'  is an even looser term.